# Show that $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1-|x-y|)$ defines a metric space in $[0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Having trouble proving the transitive property of d

Comment: What do you mean by transitive property?

Comment: $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force solution would be to consider all the 8 cases 1-by-1 to reduce the issue with minimum:

**case 1:** $|x-y| \le 0.5$ and $|y-z| \le 0.5$ and $|x-z| \le 0.5$
$$d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x, z) \implies |x-y| + |y-z| \ge |x-z|$$

**case 2:** $|x-y| \le 0.5$ and $|y-z| \le 0.5$ and $|x-z| \ge 0.5$
$$d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x, z) \implies |x-y| + |y-z| \ge |x-z| \ge 1 - |x-z|$$

**case 3:** $|x−y|\ge 0.5$  and $|y−z| \le 0.5$ and $|x−z|\le 0.5$ 
In this case since $|x-y| \ge 0.5$ but the other 2 distances are less, it follows that $z$ must be between $x$ and $y$, or in other words $|x-y| = |x-z| + |z-y|$.
$$d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x, z) \implies 1-|x-y| + |y-z| \ge |x-z| $$
$$(1 - |y-z| - |x-z|) \ge |x-z|$$
$$0.5 \ge |x-z| \text{, because of the cases presumption it's true}$$

Comment: Those are the only 2 cases I was able to prove. Could you prove for example $|x-y| \geq 0.5$ and $|y-z| \leq 0.5$ and $|x-z| \leq 0.5$?

Comment: I'm going to extend my answer to include that case.